# OV5642 Driver i2c read registers are failing

Tags: linux, camera, linux-device-driver, device-driver, i2c

I am using a customized version of i.MX6 SABRE Lite board and I  connected to OV5642. Driver Probe was successful. It successfully read the Chip ID Properly.

But when it tries to apply the initial register settings I2C is failing with timeout error. How to debug this scenario?

I am using the following driver:

https://github.com/boundarydevices/linux-imx6/blob/boundary-imx_3.10.53_1.1.1_ga/drivers/media/platform/mxc/capture/ov5642.c

My Device Tree settings:

```
ov564x: ov564x@3c {
compatible = "ovti,ov564x";
reg = <0x3c>;
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ipu1_2>;
clocks = <&clks 201>;
clock-names = "csi_mclk";
DOVDD-supply = <&vgen4_reg>;/* 1.8v */
AVDD-supply = <&vgen3_reg>; /* 2.8v, on rev C board is VGEN3,*/
DVDD-supply = <&vgen2_reg>; /* 1.5v*/
pwn-gpios = <&gpio1 19 1>; /* active low: SD1_DAT2 */
rst-gpios = <&gpio1 20 0>; /* active high: SD1_CLK */
csi_id = <0>;
mclk = <24000000>;
mclk_source = <0>;
ipu_id = <0>;
}; 

   MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_0__CCM_CLKO1            0x130b0         /* ov5642 mclk */
   MX6QDL_PAD_SD1_DAT2__GPIO1_IO19          0x80000000         /* ov5642 Power Down */
   MX6QDL_PAD_SD1_CLK__GPIO1_IO20          0x80000000       /* ov5642 Reset */
```

Following are kernel logs:

```
mxc_v4l2_master_attach: ipu0:/csi0 parallel attached ov5642:mxc_v4l2_cap0

ov5642 0-003c: created sysfs entry for reading regs

camera ov5642 is found

ov5642_write_reg:write reg error:reg=3615,val=f0 ret=-110

ov5642_apply_settings, write reg 0x3615 failed

ov5642_write_reg:write reg error:reg=3103,val=93 ret=-5

ov5642_apply_settings, write reg 0x3103 failed
```